# Question 3d from Exercises 3.3.1 fromF. Mary Hart - Guide to Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The question asks whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[]{n+1}-\sqrt[]{n-1}}{\sqrt[]{n}}$ diverges or converges. I am supposed to solve this using the comparison test (the limit version or the normal version). I tried this using the limit version but the limit I got using $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ was $0$, and the Theorem states it most be a finite non-zero limit. 
 I tried to solve this using the normal version but I was struggling to show that 
$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\sqrt[]{n+1}-\sqrt[]{n-1}}{\sqrt[]{n}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. 
The hint also says that it uses $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and that the series diverges.

Comment: Try multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}$

Comment: Multiply and divide by conjugate $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}$ then a simple comparison argument does the job

Comment: Alternate, going away from the book: use the n-th term test: the limit of the summands is 1.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I'm not familiar with the n-th term test but I'll have a look at it.